# Java Class files in tomcat not linking/updating when using eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, tomcat, servlets

I am working on an old jsp project. I have to modify it so that I can use it to meet my needs. I was facing issue while using any newer version of tomcat or java sdk. Therefore, I am using Tomcat 5.5.7 and java SDK 1.5. I have updated java class files of this project using eclipse helios (2012). But the implementation don't show up in my project. Like when I change the database name and run the project it still wants to use the old database name. I have tried to upgrade the whole project to a new version of tomcat and java sdk but it doesn't work. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: You don't really ask a specific question here.  You are asking for help in general, there are a lot of moving pieces though.  The question is good, working on old projects can be tough.  I believe you are going to need to do some research on how projects are setup in Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Steps you need to take -

Import the project into eclipse - Create a new project, import using existing source files.

You need to setup the Java Facet of "Dynamic Web Application" along with some other Facets to make this application run successfully on the tomcat container inside of eclipse.

You need to install the server tools in eclipse. Using the Java EE perspective is very helpful.

When making changes to the JDK or the server runtime, as you mentioned, you will need to update the projects build path.  Right click on the root of your project and go to the build path.  Change the SDK version, change the runtime version of tomcat that is included with it.  You will need to create a new Java Server runtime for any other versions of Tomcat you want to add to the project.

This is a complicated issue, and there is no specific answer, as your question is very broad.  I would recommend watching some tutorials on "How to setup Web application projects in Eclipse."  Maybe add Java 5 or 6 to the search to get older results.

Comment: Hi, Andrew. Thank you for your reply. The project is running fine on eclipse. And is connected with database perfectly. I can add or remove records in the database using eclipse. The problem I am facing is with java class files. Like if I want to make some changes in java files present in the project and compile it. I can see changes I have made both in java file and class file respectively. But the change is not implemented on my project if I run the project on server using eclipse. For example, if I changed the database name from the java file and from mysql.

Comment: Are you republishing when you make your changes?  Also, autobuild is on?  If you are restarting your tomcat server, the changes will only be there if autopublishing is on, or you are manually republishing the project.  You might want to double click on the server in the "server" window, and make sure that you are using the right metadata, and that the publishing options are correct for your setup.

Comment: Yes, I do find it weird. Once I make a change in java file, the change in the class file is not implemented immediately no matter how many times I refresh my project. But restarting the eclipse or opening the class file through the file directory shows the change made. Also eclipse does ask me if I want to restart my server. Is that what you mean by republishing?

Comment: I have checked in the server menu. It is set to **Automatically publish when resources change**.

Comment: If you right click on the server instance you should see "Publish".

Comment: If you right click on the artifact deployed on the server, you should see information about cleaning all information, clean publish, etc...

Comment: Thanks, Andrew. I have published the project. But the problem hasn't solved as I can't view any changes on the project deployed on server.